# Refresh datatable manually with already fetched data

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a datatable that is initialized to be "empty" with these options:

```
let options = { 
    data: [],
    columns: [],
    dataSrc: ""
}
let dataTable = $(component).DataTable(options);
```

Now this datatable should be updated from an ajax result that was **NOT** preformed by the datatable.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "service/url/path",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
         //TODO: refresh the datatable
    }
});
```

All the tutorials are essentially from these 2 types:

- Giving the datatable the ajax request's URL so that the datatable can update itself
- Giving the datatable a JS object upon initialization

What I want to do is something like this:

```
dataTable.options.columns = { .. column settings .. };
dataTable.data = newData;
dataTable.refresh();
```

How can I modify the settings/options of the dataTable?

How can I *manually* refresh the data without recreating the whole datatable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you column configuration has changed, proper way to would be to re-initialize the data table using [`destroy`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/destroy) option.

From the [manual](https://datatables.net/reference/option/destroy):

> ... If there is an existing DataTable which matches the selector, it will be destroyed and replaced with the new table. This can be useful if you want to change a property of the table which cannot be altered through the API.

For example:

```js
let options = { 
    data: newData,
    columns: [{ /* ... column settings ... */ }],
    destroy: true
}

let dataTable = $(component).DataTable(options);
```